# Count android crashes

Tags: android, logging

I need to count how many crashes of my application were on my device. How can I do that? Where to store this count? I need to create some field with a number of crashes. After every crash I should increase this number.

Comment: Here's a better idea : fix the bugs so it doesn't crash ...

Comment: Why do you want to build crashing app?

Comment: you can use [Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/) to track the crashes

Answer (score 1):

In your first onCreate in your application start this code:
Save off an int to a file in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Increase it by one everytime this code hits.

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(final Thread thread, final Throwable ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                //increase int here
                final StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                final PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
                ex.printStackTrace(pw);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("text/html");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My App is on fire!");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sw.toString());
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Crash Log"));
                Variables.activity.finish();
                System.exit(0);

            }
        });
```

This will serve your purpose and even ask them to email you the crash log. You should never have any known bugs or any need to increase a counter. This is a bad idea. But i supplied the code anyway